# Reducing a Combination of Multiple Selections to a Simpler One

Tags: sql, postgresql

Looking at the SQL below, it feels like a very verbose way to accomplish what I am trying to do. Essentially, my goal is to select all adult patients (determined by tables mimiciii.patients and mimiciii.admissions) who have a measurement of bun, hematocrit, gcs, or heart rate. BUN and hematocrit are in a table titled mimiciii.labevents, while heart rate and and GCS are in mimiciii.chartevents.

Specifically,  I have two questions:

1) Looking at the bun_hematocrit -> [GROUP BY] -> lab_counts, could this series of queries be done in one simpler one?

2) Is the intersection of these tables better than performing multiple inner joins? Or perhaps using (SELECT patient_id IN [other table])?

EDIT: I'm currently using PostgreSQL 9.6.1.

```
--Adults--

-- Determine ages.
WITH ages AS(
  SELECT
      p.subject_id, a.hadm_id, p.dob, p.gender
      , MIN (a.admittime) AS first_admittime
      , MIN( ROUND( (cast(admittime as date) - cast(dob as date)) / 365.242,2) )
          AS first_admit_age
  FROM MIMICIII.patients p
  INNER JOIN MIMICIII.admissions a
  ON p.subject_id = a.subject_id
  GROUP BY p.subject_id, a.hadm_id, p.dob, p.gender
  ),
-- Determine adults.
  adults AS(
    SELECT subject_id, hadm_id
    FROM ages
    WHERE first_admit_age >= 15
    ),
-- Determine which have necessary feature from labevents.
  bun_hematocrit AS(
    SELECT subject_id, hadm_id,
      CASE WHEN itemid IN (51006) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bun,
      CASE WHEN itemid IN (51221, 51480) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS hematocrit
      FROM MIMICIII.labevents

      ),
-- Combine necessary lab features into counts for each hospital stay.
  lab_counts AS(
      SELECT subject_id, hadm_id
      FROM bun_hematocrit
      GROUP BY subject_id, hadm_id
      HAVING (max(bun) + max(hematocrit)) >= 2
    ),
-- Determine which have necessary features from chart events.
  heart_rate_gcs AS(
    SELECT subject_id, hadm_id,
      CASE WHEN itemid IN (454, 223900) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS gcs,
      CASE WHEN itemid IN (211,220045) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS heart_rate
      FROM mimiciii.chartevents
    ),
-- Combine necessary chart features into counts for each hospital stay.
  chart_counts AS(
      SELECT subject_id, hadm_id
      FROM heart_rate_gcs
      GROUP BY subject_id, hadm_id
      HAVING (max(heart_rate) + max(gcs)) >= 2
    )
-- Get the intersection of hospital stays for adults, lab features, and chart features.
SELECT * INTO mimiciii.cohort FROM(
  SELECT subject_id, hadm_id FROM lab_counts
  INTERSECT
  SELECT subject_id, hadm_id FROM chart_counts
  INTERSECT
  SELECT subject_id, hadm_id FROM adults
) as temp;
```

Comment: The `adults` cte can be removed when you add a `having MIN( ROUND( (cast(admittime as date) - cast(dob as date)) / 365.242,2) ) >= 15`to the `ages` cte. The `ROUND( (cast(admittime as date) - cast(dob as date)) / 365.242,2)` can be simplified to `age(admittime, dob)` together with `having min(age(admittime, dob)) >= interval '15' year`

Comment: Appreciate it! Wasn't even looking for inefficiencies there.

Answer (score 0):

Complex queries can often be simplified by using temporary tables in a transaction block.